# How to move a <li> from a <ul> ato another <ul> in a separate div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i have two containers which contain separate `ul`. My objective is to move one of the child `<li>` from one `ul` to the other.

I currently have a delete function on the li within the ul using jquery, as below:

```js
//check off specific todos
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// x to delete todo /mark as complete
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

//text input
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var todotext = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        // create a new LI
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></span> " + todotext + "</li>");
    }
});


//toggles input box
$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">



<body>


<div id="container">
    <h1>Task List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input placeholder="Add new Task" type="text">

    <ul>
    <li><span><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span> hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="container-2">
    <h1>Completed Tasks <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></h1>
    
    <ul>
    
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
```

I am really new to this so just trying to personalize a project.

Comment: Use `append` or `appendTo` instead of `remove` then. An element that is already in the DOM, will then be moved from its original position to the new one.

Comment: thanks, so would i have to assign an id to the other ul and then use appendTo("ID") ?

Comment: You can select the element any way you like, it does not necessarily have to be by ID. You have to pass the jQuery object that contains that selection to the appendTo method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing, you should append the element to the target container, and then use `fadeIn` to show it again.

```js
//check off specific todos
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// x to delete todo /mark as complete
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).appendTo($("#container-2 ul")).fadeIn(500);
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

//text input
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var todotext = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        // create a new LI
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></span> " + todotext + "</li>");
    }
});


//toggles input box
$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">



<body>


<div id="container">
    <h1>Task List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input placeholder="Add new Task" type="text">

    <ul>
    <li><span><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span> hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="container-2">
    <h1>Completed Tasks <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></h1>
    
    <ul>
    
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
```